# To have whole set of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ by adding/subtracting

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Let $\mathbb{Z}_n$ be the set of integers in modulo $n$: $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$. Note that $n$ does not have to be prime.
And $S_m$ be the subset of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, containing $m$ different elements in $\mathbb{Z}_n$: $\{i_1,...,i_m\}$. We only know the number $m$, but not the set $S_m$ itself.

Then I want to have $\mathbb{Z}_n$ by adding and subtracting $S_m$:
is it possible to say that for some $m$, $\mathbb{Z}_n=S_m\pm S_m$ where $\pm$ is (Minkowski) addition and subtraction as a set in modulo $n$? Then what is the condition for $m$? (I am guessing $m\geq n/2$ would work, but not sure how to prove.)

Further, the same question for $\mathbb{Z}_n=(S_m\pm S_m)\pm S_m$, to have this, what is the conditon for $m$?

If needed, we can assume that $S_m$ contains $0$ and $1$ for $m\geq 2$, but I don't think this matters... 
[EDIT: as indicated in the comment, having $0$ and $1$ matters. It may help to have small $m$, so please assume.]

Any comment is appreciated!

Comment: Conditions on $0,1$ may matter. Consider $\mathbb{Z}_{2m}$ and the subgroup $H\subseteq\mathbb{Z}_{2m}$ of order $m$. Now if you take any subseteq $S_m\subseteq H$ then $S_m\pm \cdots\pm S_m\subseteq H\subsetneq\mathbb{Z}_{2m}$ no matter how many times you do that. But obviously $1\not\in H$. Also note that the same argument shows that $m=n/2$ is not enough.

Comment: @freakish Yes you are right, having 0 and 1 matters. So if we assume that, then $m=n/2$ can be enough...?

Comment: Without conditions on $0$ or $1$ belonging to $S_m$, it is clear that you want $m>n-\varphi(n)$. Edit: $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function. I would be inclined to think that it is sufficient, I am not sure though.

Comment: @Clément Guérin, I am not sure about the statement, if we have prime $n$, then $m=2$ is enough for however big prime $n$? Maybe my notation/explanation was bad, but $\pm$  allows only one time addition/subtraction of each element.

Comment: @2019ys, you are right.  The condition $m>n-\varphi(n)$ is $clearly$ not enough. It is necessary though (this is related to freakish's comment). Edit: BTW your notation/explanation is good, that is what I understood, I just did not bother to test with $n$ prime.